# Magento 2 : Bestseller and most viewed product on homepage

Tags: magento2, product, best-seller

How to get **bestseller and most viewed product** in homepage **Magento 2**?

We have to display *bestseller and most viewed* product list in homepage slider in magento 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For bestseller create a block in `__construct` get instance of

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
```

ex

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getBestSellerData()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel(
            'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
        );

        return $collection;
    }       

}
```

For recently viewed you can use widget from admin side or else you can write custom block 
with `\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory`

**Look at:**

```
vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Dashboard\Tab\Products\Viewed.php

and

vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Dashboard\Tab\Products\Ordered.php
```

Comment: How to get list of most viewed products?

Comment: create widget from admin , in front end call that widget, if bestsellers works for you then accept my answer so it will usefull for others

Comment: ok, i will check it first for bestseller. Thanks.

Comment: its working fine you will get product id and name, just put for each loop for the collection and print the data

Comment: its only getting first five products.Its not working as expected.I want to get first ten bestselling products.

Comment: @RBJesadiya:- in forum you will not get 100% solution for your task , you will get only ideas , if you want raise oen more new ticket  , you can try this      $collection->getSelect()->limit(10);

Comment: but any suggestion for getting first ten bestselling product?

Comment: try this $collection->getSelect()->limit(10);

Comment: best option is create your own model file which is extend from \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection and in that just set  protected $_ratingLimit = 10; reset should take from parent  class

Comment: @PradeepKumar How can i get best seller product from specific category?

Comment: @PradeepKumar I have created new question about extending model file, can please help? http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/106450/32271

Comment: @PradeepKumar its not working its product count giving 0 products.

Comment: Hello How to setup visibility in this Model like i want to product collection Catalog Search Prodcut only

Comment: How to get more than 5 most viewed products?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, how to get best seller products of a category?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to view the BEST SELLER as well as MOST VIEWED products in your Magento 2 Slider.

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();   
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); ?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind when you first launch a site, you won't have any sales data, so you'll need to add backup logic, e.g., retrieve random products from catalog if there is nothing in sales table.