# Extend model file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I'm trying to extend model file from \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection so I can change the `$_ratingLimit = 10;`

Based from example [Overriding Block, Model, Controller in Magento2](http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-block-model-controller-magento2/) What I have have so far
 `app/code/<Vendor>/<ModuleName>/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" />
</config>
```

And `app/code/<Vendor>/<ModuleName>/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_ratingLimit = 10;   
}
```

Obvisously I am doing something or all wrong. I need help. Thank you.

Comment: check in var/log/system.log

Comment: I do find some errors, but after clearing the log file and removing above files. It generates exact identical errors. So, I dont think any of them are related to this.

Comment: lot of bug i there 1. you should not use preferences, use plugin if not at all possible then use preferences. 2. you should extend  AbstractCollection, it should be Bestsellers/collection,

Comment: @PradeepKumar In my case, `$_ratingLimit` is non public variable, do I still able to use plug-in class?

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestions. I was able to increase limit with the preference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it is the only post I could find online that was related to the issue I was having. I used this questions code as a starting point, but I couldn't understand what @Pradeep Kumar comment was referring to in regards to extending the class.

I finally figured out what they were referring to, so hopefully this helps someone else out that stumbles across this question.

I changed:

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_ratingLimit = 10;   
}
```

to:

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection
{
  protected $_ratingLimit = 12;
}
```

The problem was that by extending `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection` it was replacing the existing Collection class, but by extending `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection` you are basically editing the existing Collection class.

**NOTE** 
Remember this code needs to be part of a custom module. [https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/]. That stumped me for a while :)