# How to display best selling products on homepage in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am new in magento 2. Could you please describe in detail how can I get best selling products on homepage in Magento 2. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ Keerthana Check the answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/magento-2-bestseller-and-most-viewed-product-on-homepage

Comment: @krishna ijjada  As I already said, I am new in magento 2, so I am not able to understand where to write this 'Test' class. I am sorry, if my question is quite simple. Please help me..