# How to display top viewed products and best selling products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have to display best selling products and top viewed products in my magento 2. Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Refer this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/magento-2-bestseller-and-most-viewed-product-on-homepage

Comment: http://www.eglobeits.com/magento2-bestseller-module-by-eglobeits.html