# Magento 2 - Bestseller product collection

Tags: magento2, product, collection, best-seller

I am trying to get bestseller products on homepage using product collection in **Magento 2**.
I only got Most Viewed product listing (?) and I am not getting bestseller products.

**Here is my code:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('status','1')
          ->setPageSize(8)
          ->load();
```

Can someone tell me which **ResourceModel** I need to load? I tried with:

```
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory`enter code here`
```

But didn't helped (I got some error with that code and that resource).

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/magento-2-bestseller-and-most-viewed-product-on-homepage try this link.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156207/magento-2-get-best-seller-product-on-daily-basis

Answer (score 3):

Try code below :

```
protected $_collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
public function getBestSellerData(){
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
        ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
        ->setPeriod('month'); //you can add period daily,yearly
        //->setPeriod('year');
        //->setPeriod('day');

    return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

M2 have some tables related to bestsell `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily` 
`sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`

In code you can filter bestsell by method `joinField`
 you can do this

```
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId();
/** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addStoreFilter()
        ->joinField(
            'qty_ordered',
            'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly',
            'qty_ordered',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'at_qty_ordered.store_id='.$storeId,
            'at_qty_ordered.qty_ordered > 0',
            'left'
        )->setPageSize(8)->setCurPage(1);
return $collection;
```

Comment: What i understand it's working in own module, it's doesn't work in theme custom block. I need add some referencje/attributes to this block?

Comment: I think, Magento 2 using default `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` table to get bestseller product, How can get best seller products using `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code in that you can also filter the product by Month,year or day .

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

//$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('year');
//$collection->setPeriod('day');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('year');
//$collection->setPeriod('day');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U can used this code and get the Bestseller Product,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('year');
//$collection->setPeriod('day');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

after used this code ,
In order for best selling products to show up in your magento website go to Reports > Refresh Statistics select all items > "Refresh Lifetime Statistics" -> submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$productsCollection = $this->getProductsCollection();
$productsCollection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        'sales_order_item',
        'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id and sales_order_item.store_id = ' . $store->getId() . ' and date(sales_order_item.created_at) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL '. $daysInterval .' DAY)',
        [
            'bestsellers' => 'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)'
        ]
    )
    ->group('e.entity_id')
    ->having('SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered) > 0')
    ->order('bestsellers desc');

return $productsCollection;
```