# Magento 2 : get best seller product on daily basis

Tags: magento-2.1, product, best-seller

There are some tables related to **bestseller** in Magento 2 and it is using following tables to get best product collection.

```
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
```

I think, **magento2** use `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` table for best seller products. I am using `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory` and it is working fine.

**I am getting the bestseller collection yearly basis**. How can i achieve bestseller collection by monthly basis or daily basis.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If I want to get collection of last 2 months then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

//$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('year');
$collection->setPeriod('day');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: are there any differences from my answer?

Comment: @Max There is no difference in terms of logic. You only  posted the logic of setting intervals and I posted the complete code. That's it.

Comment: @DineshYadav, can you provide the code with constructor rather than directly with objectManager

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection::setPeriod` method for define aggregation interval.

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory */
$collection = $collectionFactory->create();
$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('day');
//$collection->setPeriod('year');
```

Also you can look at `Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\AbstractGrid` for clarify interaction with magento base Report Collections.

Comment: Can you put full answer actually i may making some mistakes so i am not able to get output