# How to get Best Selling Product Collection in Magento 2 using Object Manager

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, best-seller

How can I get "**Monthly Best selling product**" in Magento 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('year');
//$collection->setPeriod('day');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: did you know how can i get best selling product on monthly and daily bases?                                                                                                                       I refer this link but cant get actual idea :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156207/magento-2-get-best-seller-product-on-daily-basis

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: how to add filters for avoid out of stock and not visible individually from best sellers collection?

Comment: can you please look into this issue? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239155/how-to-ignore-not-avilable-products-from-best-seller-product-collection

Comment: do we need to pass anything instead of month? Please update full code

Comment: I used 'day' in setPeriod, but still i am getting old collection

Comment: Try reindexing the product collection. Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command.

Comment: @DineshYadav, How to get only latest month's best seller products. $resourceCollection->setPeriod('DESC'); ?

Comment: @DineshYadav, how I can get best seller just like admin dashboard i.e without specify period ?

Comment: how can we get today, last month, last 3 month best seller product using this code?