# How to create best seller page in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, products, best-seller

I am trying to create a page where all best sellers products should be displayed and it needs to look like magento's default category page(filters on the left and product grid/list on the right).

I made a custom page then tried to reuse most of `Magento_Catalog` resources like blocks, templates, etc. The problem is, most of the functions uses `getCurrentCategory()` which seems not applicable in my case.

Any insights how can I do it?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198708/how-to-get-best-selling-product-collection-in-magento-2-using-object-manager?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Nits I already got the idea on how to pull the data. Is there a way that I can use it in place of product collection in category or do I have to make my own?