# How to ignore not avilable products from best seller product collection?

Tags: magento2, product, collection, best-seller

> app/code/Test/Demo/Block/Widget/Bestsellerdproduct.php

```
namespace Test\Demo\Block\Widget;
class Bestsellerdproduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'widget/bestsellerdproduct.phtml';

    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;
    const DEFAULT_IMAGE_WIDTH = 150;
    const DEFAULT_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 150;
    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_productsCount;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;
    protected $_resourceFactory;
    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Image helper
     *
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $_imageHelper;
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     */
    protected $_cartHelper;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $resourceFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\Grouped\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Helper\Data $reportsData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_resourceFactory = $resourceFactory;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_reportsData = $reportsData;
        $this->_imageHelper = $context->getImageHelper();
        $this->_cartHelper = $context->getCartHelper();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Image helper Object
     */
    public function imageHelperObj(){
        return $this->_imageHelper;
    }
    /**
     * get featured product collection
     */
   public function getBestsellerProduct(){
        $limit = $this->getProductLimit();       
        $resourceCollection = $this->_resourceFactory->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection');
        $resourceCollection->setPageSize($limit);
        return $resourceCollection;
   }

    /**
     * Get the configured limit of products
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductLimit() {
        if($this->getData('productcount')==''){
            return DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->getData('productcount');
    }
     /**
     * Get the widht of product image
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductimagewidth() {
        if($this->getData('imagewidth')==''){
            return DEFAULT_IMAGE_WIDTH;
        }
        return $this->getData('imagewidth');
    }
     /**
     * Get the height of product image
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductimageheight() {
        if($this->getData('imageheight')==''){
            return DEFAULT_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
        }
        return $this->getData('imageheight');
    }
    /**
     * Get the add to cart url
     * @return string
     */
     public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = [])
    {
            return $this->_cartHelper->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    }
     /**
     * Return HTML block with price
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param string $priceType
     * @param string $renderZone
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function getProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $priceType = null,
        $renderZone = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        if (!isset($arguments['zone'])) {
            $arguments['zone'] = $renderZone;
        }
        $arguments['zone'] = isset($arguments['zone'])
            ? $arguments['zone']
            : $renderZone;
        $arguments['price_id'] = isset($arguments['price_id'])
            ? $arguments['price_id']
            : 'old-price-' . $product->getId() . '-' . $priceType;
        $arguments['include_container'] = isset($arguments['include_container'])
            ? $arguments['include_container']
            : true;
        $arguments['display_minimal_price'] = isset($arguments['display_minimal_price'])
            ? $arguments['display_minimal_price']
            : true;
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product,
                $arguments
            );
        }
        return $price;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Test/Demo/view/frontend/templates/widget/bestsellerdproduct.phtml

```
    <?php
   if ($exist = ($this->getBestsellerProduct() && $this->getBestsellerProduct()->getPageSize())) {
   $fet_prodcollection = $this->getBestsellerProduct();
   $productcount = $this->getProductLimit();
   $imagewidth = $this->getProductimagewidth();
   $imageheight = $this->getProductimageheight();
   $mode = 'grid';
   $title = __('Best Sellers');
   $type  = 'widget-bestseller-grid';
   $image = 'bestseller_products_content_widget_grid';
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   }
   ?>
<?php if ($exist):?>
<div class="block widget block-bestseller-products <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?>">
<div class="block-title">
   <strong role="heading" aria-level="2"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $title; ?></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
<div class="products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?>">
   <ol class="product-items owl-carousel <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $type; ?>" id="bestSellers">
      <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
      <?php foreach ($fet_prodcollection as $item):  
            $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
            //for avoiding not Not Visible Individually
            if($_product->getVisibility() !='1' && $_product->getIsSalable()){         
         ?>   
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
      <div class="product-item-info">
         <?php
            $imagewidth='170'; 
            $imageheight ='170';
            $image_url = $block->imageHelperObj()->init($_product, 'product_base_image')
                        ->setImageFile($_product->getFile())
                        ->resize($imagewidth,$imageheight)
                        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                        ->getUrl();                       
            ?>
         <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-item-photo">
         <img src="<?php echo  $image_url;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" />
         </a>
         <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
            <a title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>"
               href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
               class="product-item-link">
            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>
            </a>
            </strong>
            <?php
               echo $this->getProductPriceHtml($_product, $type);
               ?>
            <div class="product-item-actions">
               <div class="actions-primary">
                  <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                  <?php if ($_product->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_product)): ?>
                  <button class="action tocart primary"
                     data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl":{"url":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"}}'
                     type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                  <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                  </button>
                  <?php else: ?>
                    <?php
                     $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                     $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_product), ['product' => $_product->getId()]);
                    ?>
                  <button class="action tocart primary" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postData; ?>'                  type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                  <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                  </button>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php else: ?>
                  <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                  <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                  <?php else: ?>
                  <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php echo($iterator == count($fet_prodcollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
      <?php endforeach ?>
   </ol>
</div>

<?php endif;?>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can add status, visibility and stock status filter into collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good to join the stock filter in your collection for better performance.
However seeing your code you already have any answer for it.

```
$_product->getIsSalable()
```

Check this at top before creating your product div.

Comment: and more point @priyank in the collection we are getting not visible individual production how to avoid ?

Comment: Hi @priyank one small help from the collection we are getting empty records (products not available) how to avoid please advise?

Comment: Hi @priyank i would like to exclude empty records and want to display out of stock from the collection could you please advise.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa what do you mean by empty records?

Comment: empty records means deleted products earlier. shall i update my block and template code here so that u will get an idea what i am doing currently.

Comment: Yes pls update your code. Not getting what you want exactly. If you delete products you will not get those records in collection.

Comment: yes priyank code updated.

Comment: Its better you create a new question for same as this something else then you have asked previously.