# Magento 2 : How to get best seller product collection using object manager in home page custom slider?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, object-manager

How to add best seller products in home page custom slider. So, I need a best seller product collection in phtml file.

Comment: Similar question here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198708/how-to-get-best-selling-product-collection-in-magento-2-using-object-manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Best Selling Product Collection in Magento 2 using Object Manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198708/how-to-get-best-selling-product-collection-in-magento-2-using-object-manager)

Comment: I tried same as your suggestion. But it will not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use always construct method instead of oject manager. Add below code in your block file :

```
protected $_collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
   \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
   \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
   array $data = []
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getBestSellerCollection() {
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setPeriod('month');        
    return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;
}
```

and add this code in phtml :

```
$bestSeller =  $block->getBestSellerCollection();
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: how I can get best seller just like admin dashboard i.e without specify period ?