# How to display "customer based" best sellers list?

Tags: magento2, best-seller

I would like to build a custom module, for Magento 2, that will displays a list of products, from the logged in customer's, order history, and sort it by the best selling products.
(e.g. most occurrences in the orders history of that customer)

Comment: You can try to use this code to get your result : [Best selling product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156207/magento-2-get-best-seller-product-on-daily-basis)

Comment: You can try to use this code to get your result : [Best selling product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156207/magento-2-get-best-seller-product-on-daily-basis)

Comment: Thanks Shashank, but what I'm looking for is a way to get a collection of all orders and extract the products (with quantities) from all of 'em and calculate the most occurrences from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out.

Here is my working code:

```
    class MostBought extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMostBoughtProducts()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

        $customerOrders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);

        $products = array();
        foreach($customerOrders as $order){
            foreach($order->getAllItems() as $product){
                if (array_key_exists($product->getSku(), $products)){
                    $products[$product->getSku()] += (int)$product->getQtyOrdered();
                }else{
                    $products[$product->getSku()] = (int)$product->getQtyOrdered();
                }
            }
        }
        arsort($products);
        $skuList = implode(",", array_slice(array_keys($products), 0, 4));
        return $skuList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modify [Best selling product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156207/magento-2-get-best-seller-product-on-daily-basis)

this  according to your need -:

1. collect the collection,  group by orderid .
2. setorder descending then you easily make uniques product array and setPageSize() depend on your need .